# CPP Reads from File but EXE Doesn't

Tags: c++, file-io, command-prompt, iostream

The .cpp file reads from a .txt file, compiles, runs, and outputs perfectly. I want the output saved to a .txt file, so I'm accessing the program from command prompt.

I'm using %PATH%Program.exe>%PATH%P4RESULTS.TXT

It runs the program, but P4RESULTS.TXT always shows "Unable to read file. Program terminating." I haven't moved or renamed the file - it's in with the .cpp. I checked the file extension to see if I'd double-named the inFile (.txt.txt) but that's not it.

Has anyone seen anything like this? Is there something obvious I'm missing? My input file opening method included below. Just baffled why it's seeing and reading the file in VS2013 but not from .exe. Thanks.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define TABLESIZE     100
    #define KEYSIZE       4
    #define EMPTYKEY      "----"
    #define DATAFILE      "P4DATA.txt"
    using namespace std;
    int main(void)
    {
        ifstream     *inFile;
        InitTable(T, TABLESIZE);       
        inFile = new ifstream();
        inFile->open(DATAFILE, ifstream::in);  
      if (!inFile->is_open())
      {
        cout << "Unable to open data file. Program terminating.\n";
        return 0;
      }//end inFile check
    }
```

Comment: Is `P4DATA.txt` in the current working directory of the command prompt that you ran the exe from?

Comment: `%PATH%Program.exe>%PATH%P4RESULTS.TXT` I hope you are putting some path in there and not really using `%PATH%`

Comment: The program is expecting `P4DATA.txt` to be in the current working directory when you executed the program. Does `dir` show both `exe` and `txt` in the directory before and after you ran the `exe` including `P4RESULTS.TXT`?

Comment: Yes, I am putting a real path in there and not %PATH%. P4DATA.txt .... Now that's a good question. The command prompt shows as C:\Users\Name - and all my files are in C:\Users\Name\Documents....etc., so yes?

Comment: The folder has the .exe file. The P4DATA.txt is in the folder with the .cpp file. When I run the prompt, it creates P4RESULTS.txt. P4DATA.txt is still there. I tried putting P4DATA.txt in the folder with the .exe file and got the same results.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you say `Program.exe`, you're not talking about this program whose code you have shown?

Comment: Yes, but this isn't all of the code, just a bit showing the infile stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%PATH%` is set to a sequence of <kbd>;</kbd>-separated directories, used to locate an executable if the executable doesn't exist within the current directory. Try using `mypath` in place of `path` and set `mypath` to the directoryname of the executable

```
set "mypath=c:\wherever\whatever"
pushd "%mypath%"
"%mypath%\yourprogram.exe">"%mypath%\P4RESULTS.TXT"
popd
```

The quotes overcome problems with spaces in file/directorynames. The quotes in the `set` command ensure that trailing spaces on the line are not included in the value assigned to `mydir`.

The pushd/popd ceremony would temporarily change the current directory to `mypath`. Actually, under those circumstances, referencing `mypath` would not be necessary in the `.exe` line.

OR

```
set "mypath=c:\wherever\whatever"
pushd "path to directory containing p4data.txt"
"%mypath%\yourprogram.exe">"%mypath%\P4RESULTS.TXT"
popd
```

may also fix the problem

Comment: The issue remains where the application can't find the data file because the current working directory didn't have the `P4DATA.txt`. Try adding a line to `cd %mypath%` before executing the application.

Comment: Thank you so much, you two. It didn't work at first until I added cd %mypath%.